# Unable to access property of a class after it throws exception

Tags: php, class, oop

I have a PHP class which for this example I'm just calling `MyClass`. If something goes wrong in this class, it throws an exception which I'm catching. In this catch block, I need to access some public class properties of `MyClass` but for some reason they're all returning `NULL`. Code below.

```
try {
    $myClass= new \sys\global\MyClass($id);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die(var_dump($myClass->reading));
}
```

The above is printing `NULL` to the page, even though `reading` is a public property of `MyClass`:

```
namespace sys\global;

class MyClass {
    public $reading = 10;

    // ... other class code
}
```

I've even done `die(var_dump($this->reading))` inside the class just before the exception is thrown and it has the value `10`.

Does throwing an exception in a class destroy it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an exception is thrown inside the constructor, the object is not created. i.e. You can't access the attributes of an object that does not exist.

Comment: The last line of the constructor calls a method which throws the exception. It makes sense that the constructor is waiting for that method to "finish", meaning the object isn't fully created yet. Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisWhite You could catch the exception inside your constructor if the return value of the method in question is not vital to the object's existence.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what the exception was, you may not be able to access the members. It would appear in this situation that your exception is caused in the constructor of `$myClass`, so I doubt your object is getting created properly, therefore meaning you can't access its properties.